# C# NAudio 3D Sound

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I've programmed a program that can play a sound as normal, but how do you set the position of the sound that is 3D or at least you can set how strong the sound should be on the right and how strong the sound should be on the left?

Here is my code so far:

```
WaveOut wavOut = new WaveOut();
            wavOut.Init(new BlockAlignReductionStream(new WaveFileReader(File.OpenRead("Wav File")));
            wavOut.Play();

            while(wavOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(250);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a stereo recording, there is no "3D" component to it.

Perhaps you want to adjust the loudness of the left and right channels instead. If so, you can experiment with the WaveChannel32 class to control the panning - see here: https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/e359ca0566e9f9b14fee1ba6e0ec17e4482c7844/NAudio/Wave/WaveStreams/WaveChannel32.cs

Pass the WaveFileReader to it and supply the appropriate panning value (-1 >= x <= 1), then init the WaveOut with WaveChannel32 instance.

```
WaveOut wavOut = new WaveOut();
wavOut.Init(new WaveChannel32(new WaveFileReader(File.OpenRead("WavFile"), 0, 0)); // the last argument in the WaveChannel32 is the pan value
wavOut.Play();
```